# Unable to send uploaded form file to express server

Tags: express, multer

I'm using [Redux-Form](http://redux-form.com/6.4.3/) to create a form that has input fields as well as a field to upload a file. I eventually want to grab that file and upload it to AWS S3, rather than storing it to a destination on my server. My issue is with grabbing the file on the server. From the client (browser), I can console.log my form values, specifically the field of my uploaded file and I get this:

```
{
  lastModified: 1484133350000,
  lastModifiedDate: Wed Jan 11 2017 06:15:50 GMT-0500 (EST),
  name: "sample_tix.pdf",
  size: 6872,
  type: "application/pdf",
  webkitRelativePath: "",
}
```

However, when it hits my express server and I console.log my file, it displays as:

```
{}
```

I'm not exactly sure why the file information appears on the client, but not on the server.

I read up a little on [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer), however it seems to return undefined when I have my server set up as such:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const multer = require('multer');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/my-api', multer().single(), function(req, res, next) {
  const values = req.body;
  const uploadedFile = req.files;
  console.log(uploadedFile); //undefined
});
```

I should be able to pull out the uploaded file information from `req.files`, but it comes back as `undefined`.

I'm not sure what the issue is exactly so any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**UPDATE:** Here is my redux action that makes the request to the server:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  CREATE_LISTING_SUCCESS,
  CREATE_ANOTHER_LISTING,
} from './types';
import { url } from '../../api/config';

export function createListing(values, userId) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.post(`${url}/my-api`, {
      values,
      userId,
    }).then(payload => {
      dispatch({
        type: CREATE_LISTING_SUCCESS,
        payload: payload.data,
      });
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you make the request to the server?

Comment: @OB3 Thanks, just added the action that makes a post request to my api.